# Why does my webrequest return an error 400 when I'm sure my XML is right?

Tags: c#, xml, httpwebrequest

I have tried sending data to an API through C#. It is my first time doing so and I unfortunately only get an error 400 when making my request.
I followed the exemple in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-an-http-post-web-request) to make my request, (using method C) but to no avail.
Here's the code I have, which follow the exemple, save for creating the XML itself. That said, for the purpose of my test, I extracted the result of my serialization into a variable. Her's the code:

```
        var serializerRequest = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Request.ImportRequest));
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        serializerRequest.Serialize(stream, importRequest);
        stream.Flush();


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Url);
        byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(stream.GetBuffer())));
        String test = new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(stream.GetBuffer()));
        request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
        request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        request.Method = "POST";
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }



        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine(response.ToString());


        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();

            XmlSerializer serializerResponse = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response.Result));
            using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(new string(Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(stream.GetBuffer()))))
            {
                Response.Result result = (Response.Result)serializerResponse.Deserialize(reader);
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
```

And here's the XML that is being sent.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ImportRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Login>
    <Username>XXXXXXX</Username>
    <Password>PPPPPPPPP</Password>
  </Login>
  <Test>True</Test>
  <ClientID>9999</ClientID>
  <Reference>8888888</Reference>
  <ShipTo>
    <Name>CLIENTNAME</Name>
    <Address1>ADDRESS</Address1>
    <Address2 />
    <City>NAMUR</City>
    <State>BE</State>
    <PostalCode>5000</PostalCode>
    <Country>BELGIUM</Country>
    <Phone />
  </ShipTo>
  <ShippingLane>
    <Region>LandMark Brussels</Region>
  </ShippingLane>
  <ShipMethod>LGINTSTD</ShipMethod>
  <ItemsCurrency>EUR</ItemsCurrency>
  <ProduceLabel>true</ProduceLabel>
  <LabelFormat>ZPL</LabelFormat>
  <LabelEncoding>ZPL</LabelEncoding>
  <VendorInformation>
    <VendorName>XXXXXXXXX</VendorName>
    <VendorAddress1>ADDRESS</VendorAddress1>
    <VendorCity>NAMUR</VendorCity>
    <VendorState>BE</VendorState>
    <VendorPostalCode>5000</VendorPostalCode>
    <VendorCountry>Belgium</VendorCountry>
    <VendorBusinessNumber>+3255555555</VendorBusinessNumber>
  </VendorInformation>
  <Packages>
    <Package>
      <Weight>10</Weight>
      <DimensionsUnit>Kg</DimensionsUnit>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</ImportRequest>
```

What bothers me the most is that when I put the XML into postman it work without an itch. So I'm convinced my XML is working, and I followed the guide on how to make webrequest, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. I get an error 400 so I'm reaching the server. It's certainly an issue with my code, but I can't find it. I would appreciate some help. 
Thanks and have a nice day.

Comment: Not all servers are the same.  The default headers in c# are not the same as Postman.  So best method of fixing issue is use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.  Then compare headers in  the first request in Postman with headers in first request in c#.  Make the headers in c# look exactly like the working Postman headers.

Answer (score 0):

In this [link](https://restfulapi.net/http-status-codes/) you will found all result code

In this case error code 400 it refers to error client, that is 
"400 (Bad Request)
400 is the generic client-side error status, used when no other 4xx error code is appropriate. Errors can be like malformed request syntax, invalid request message parameters, or deceptive request routing etc.

The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications."